# Getting a textual overview of a system's LVM configuration

Tags: linux, debian, lvm

We are making extensive use of the logical volume manager (LVM) on our Debian servers. But I find it hard to get a good overview on which partitions (LVM as well as native) I have mounted where, from which LV (logical volume) from which VG (volume group) and from which PV (physical volume). There are console tools like "lvdisplay -v" and "lvs" but those always just give me a partial view of everything. What I'd wish for is a textual representation something like:

```
Volume group "vgmain"
=======================
consists of physical volumes:
- /dev/sda1 (300 GB, 50 GB unused)
- /dev/sdb1 (300 GB, 120 GB unused)
- /dev/sdc1 (300 GB, nothing unused)

provides logical volumes:
- lvroot (EXT3 mounted on /, 4 GB, 0.5 GB free)
- lvmysql (XFS mounted on /var/lib/mysql, 8 GB used, 2 GB free)

Volume group "vghuge"
=======================
consists of physical volumes:
- /dev/sdc2 (800 GB, 250 GB unused)

provides logical volumes:
- lvhome (XFS mounted on /home, 300 GB, 90 GB free)
- lvbackup (XFS mounted on /mnt/backup, 300 GB, 20 GB free)
```

Just as an idea how that might look. Is there such a tool? If nothing like that exists yet I think I'll have to script something myself which queries "df", "lvdisplay", "vgdisplay" and "pvdisplay" and creates such an overview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/PGScully/lvmsummary/tree/master) didn't take long to write.

Comment: +1 Beats my cheesy script for completeness, although when I run it, I noticed it's missing volume groups?

Comment: Hmm, it finds all (both) of my volume groups.

Comment: Do you have names like vgdata and vgdata2, and vgdata is not displayed (and vgdata2 maybe displayed twice)?  If so, try changing 'grep $vgname' to 'grep -w $vgname'.

Comment: pgs, your script is awesome. Thanks for your contribution. It was even new to me that lvdisplay can show which physical volumes a certain logical volume is living upon. I'll surely deploy this script on my servers.

Comment: Noticed the script just yet. Nice work. RHEL-like fstabs have entries like /dev/VG/LV though, not /dev/mapper/VG-LV. That is even though the mount command shows the latter mounted, not the former.

Comment: OK, pushed an update to github than I hope will handle that.

Comment: Link to script gives a 404 on Github.

Comment: @swmcdonnell updated with new location.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU Parted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/index.shtml) can give you most of the information you need with

```
parted -l
```

It seems It only fails to effectively link lvm parttion to device mapper devices. I am sure they will welcome your patch. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Cheesy, but it shows everything (except where the filesystems are mounted).  Save it as `/usr/sbin/lvms`

```
#!/bin/sh
#lvms command - consolidates all LVM views into a single command
pvscan 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
vgscan 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
lvscan 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
echo "Available Physical Volumes - - - - - - -"
pvs
echo
echo "Active Volume Groups - - - - - - - - - -"
vgs
echo
echo "Active Logical Volumes - - - - - - - - -"
lvs
```

Follow-up:
Pgs (on this page) has provided a much nicer script.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think such a script exists. Would be a pretty cool thing to script though. I might actually look into that myself, the next time I have my weekly day-of-scripting ;-)